# Google Play Service can't authenticate , Op: SIGN_IN status: 10

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I use Unity 2017.2 for our project, and we use Google Play SDK for login for the Android.

For test version it works fine, if I can recall correctly, but when we start publish the service and turn off the alpha and beta test phase, it won't login at all.

I checked the debug using logcat and it shows this (ignore the code template, for some reason StackOverflow won't let me post the log without it):

```js
[Play Games Plugin DLL] 03/21/18 13:
04:57 +07:00 DEBUG: Starting Auth Transition. Op: SIGN_IN status: 10
03-21 13:04:57.241 7463 7479 I Unity : UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat
(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
03-21 13:04:57.241 7463 7479 I Unity : UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Objec
t)
03-21 13:04:57.241 7463 7479 I Unity : GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHel
perObject:Update()
03-21 13:04:57.241 7463 7479 I Unity :
03-21 13:04:57.241 7463 7479 I Unity : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/Andr
oid/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
03-21 13:04:57.241 7463 7479 I Unity :
03-21 13:04:57.244 7463 7479 I Unity : [Play Games Plugin DLL] 03/21/18 13:
04:57 +07:00 DEBUG: AuthState == Unauthenticated calling auth callbacks with failure
```

My main concern is this line:

> Starting Auth Transition. Op: SIGN_IN status: 10

I already googled all over the place, and can only see thread about:

> SIGN_IN status: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZE

but not:

> SIGN_IN status: 10

Are they the same? If not, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems Statuscode 10 means that your app is misconfigured in the google play developer console so you should check it there.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes.html#DEVELOPER_ERROR) is an overview of all common statuscodes in Google Play. Number 10 corresponds to DEVELOPER_ERROR.